# throw user defined exception message when an unregistered dependency is resolved

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor

I have 1 service like below

```
public interface IGopalSharma
{

}
```

Now, if I forgot the implementation of this interface IGopalSharma and use this service in constructor as below

```
private readonly IGopalSharma _gopalSharma;

public ClientsController(IGopalSharma gopalSharma)
{
    _gopalSharma = gopalSharma ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(
        "An implementation of IGopalSharma must be provided");
}
```

So I want to return this `"An implementation of IGopalSharma must be provided"` msg.

but something different is coming.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SAPI.Services.Interface.IGopalSharma' while attempting to activate 'SAPI.API.Controllers.ClientsController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

[image]

I want custom msg here. How can I do it?

Comment: This is an XY problem. What you're really after is global error handling, which doesn't print errors and stack traces to the the response.

Comment: The message "Unable to resolve service for type '{X}' while attempting to activate '{Y}'" is MS.DI's way of saying "An implementation of {X} must be provided". There's no way to override this, so which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Steven - I want to override the message basically ! is there any way ?

Comment: This is a standard error message that effectively tells you exactly what your replacement message does also. What benefit is there to doing this, other than to confuse other developers?

Comment: @GOPAL SHARMA: No, there is no way to override that message.